# Android Instrumented Unit Test - How to mock member object?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to write an instrumented unit test for the following fragment.

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment implements OnRestCompleted {

    private int id;

    public static MyListFragment getInstance(int id) {
        MyListFragment res = new MyListFragment();
        res.setId(id);
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RestCall call = new RestCall(this, id);
        call.execute();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_view, container, false);;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void RestUpdate(int eventId, Object data, Map<String, String> headers) {

        if (data instanceof MyListItem[] && ((MyListItem[]) data).length > 0) {
            addArray((MyListItem[])data);
        }
    }
}
```

When the View is being created I make a Rest call to the server to retrieve some data. How can I mock the `RestCall` object and force the test to call `RestUpdate` with the static data I want to test with?

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<FragmentTestActivity> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        FragmentTestActivity.class);

@Before
public void setup() {
    onView(withId(R.id.show_my_list_fragment_button)).perform(click());
}

@Test
public void checkLayout() {
    // TODO: Mock the request and pass the data in test data back to the fragment. If possible.
    onView(withId(R.id.title)).check(matches(withText(R.string.details)));
}
```